# How to get back a backpack lost on train or airport in Germany?

Tags: air-travel, trains, germany, airports, lost-luggage

I landed at Frankfurt airport terminal, and I had my luggage until  I had to take the train going to Frankfurt hbf. After reaching my destination, I realized I lost my backpack.
The bag contains a laptop and important papers as well as the usual carry-on items.

Comment: If your laptop is a Mac you can try to use the “Find My” service. Other non-Apple devices may have similar features.

Comment: Is there your name and contact details on that Ethiopian Airlines tag? If so, I think you may assume that anyone who finds your backpack  will contact you, if they have good intentions.

Comment: @NotThatGuy Reminds me of someone at school back in the day, who told us one day that she'd lost a set of keys to her family's home. It was all okay, though, she assured us, because her name and address were attached to them . (true story)

Comment: Just a bit of info that might give you some hope: I personally know multiple instances of people losing valuable luggage on Deutsche Bahn trains - and I have done so myself in the past, so I know it can be nerve-wracking :) But in my experience, the luggage was eventually returned, almost untouched, every time. (sometimes cash was missing or the package showed some signs of having been handled a little roughly, but laptops and other valuables were all fine.)

Answer (score 55):

We're just strangers on the internet, so we're not in a position to look for your bag based on your description.

You can report your lost item to the [Frankfurt Airport lost & found](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/airport-guide/lost-and-found-at-frankfurt-airport.html) or [Deutsche Bahn lost & found](https://www.bahn.com/en/view/home/info/lost-luggage.shtml) (covers the S-Bahn Rhein-Main as well) depending on where you think you lost it, or both if you're unsure. If it's turned in, they can match it to your report and contact you to arrange a way to get it to you. You'll likely have to pay some fees to claim it, as detailed on those pages.

If you have travel insurance, you can check to see whether this is covered under your policy, but this sort of loss may be excluded from coverage.

Comment: Maybe also add the lost&found of the city of Frankfurt, they are not supposed to have items that were found in public transport, but this seems to be worth covering all bases. https://frankfurt.de/service-und-rathaus/verwaltung/aemter-und-institutionen/ordnungsamt/fundbuero

Comment: You should also follow up on it; they may have not received it when you first contact them, and may not call you if it comes in later. If it's valuable, it can be worthwhile to call back several times (leaving time between). Look into how long they keep items, and call just before the deadline.

Answer (score 15):

Based on personal experience: About one hour into a train journey from Berlin to Dresden, we noticed an expensive looking camera under one of the seats. We stopped the next conductor who told us they had already received a call and we’re looking for the camera. The camera went on the next train back to Berlin and would have arrived there probably 90 minutes later.

They *may* send the item to you by train for free, for example if the camera owner had gone from Berlin to another station, at their discretion and if you disclaim any responsibility.